# Strange hg log output

Tags: bash, mercurial

Each morning at 10:00 crontab is setup to run this command in a bash script (the below dates are an example, they are calculated using the linux date command in the script):

```
hg log -R some-repo -b some-branch --date "2012-11-28 10:00 to 2012-11-29 10:00"
```

The above command is run on the server with the remote repo where all developers push their code. The output is stored in a string and send to me via email. But its always empty! If I run the script manually a few minutes later I get the expected output.

I have compared the history before the script is run by crontab and verified that something has indeed been committed/pushed to the remote repo.

Any ideas why running the above script AFTER 10:00 gives the correct output and not when run at 10:00?

In the script I do this:

```
logString=$(hg log -R "$path-to-repo" -b $branch --date "$YESTERDAY to $TODAY")
if [ -z "$logString" ]; then
   logString="Nothing"
fi
```

EDIT: The hg log is ONLY empty when the script is run by crontab.

SOLVED: I needed to specify the full path to hg (/usr/local/bin/hg) for cron to see it. A bit strange since it does not need have the full path to svn and it has worked fine previously without the full path to hg.

How do I see what cron has in its PATH?

Comment: under which user this crontab job executed? Intercept job's stderr also - maybe it can't auth

Comment: The same user that I log in and run the script with manually. Logs for svn commits are also generated/send and they work fine.

Comment: Stderr?! And "after 10" correct output in crontab or only by hand?

Comment: I can verify that the hg log is only  empty when the script is executed by crontab (I have enabled the crontab job with 'crontab -e'). What do you mean by Stderr for the job?

Comment: Stderr is stderr stream, output of errors. [Read this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) and monitor errors of cronjob

Comment: No idea what you mean. Should I redirect crontab to write errors to a file, like: crontab &>file? And where should I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20334/discussion-between-u123-and-lazy-badger)

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` has a very limited environment.  If you are assuming that certain variables are going to be available from your .profile (or equivalent) it's most likely not going to be there.  If you need it you will have to source it into your script.

It also looks like you you have included a snippet of a longer script.  Make the simplest script that should work and add it to the cron.  That will make it easier to debug.  For example, if you hard-code the dates in the script, you should be able to get it to work.  Once you have that working you can gradually add complexity until you figure out what's not working.

Comment: Yes that is what I have just done so now its down to one line and the problem was that I needed to specify the full path to the hg executable in the script for cron to see it. This is not necessary when I run it manually